# Create a line chart with many axes origins with ability to filter

Tags: excel, charts

I am new to Excel with regards to creating charts and I am having some difficulty in trying to achieve what I want. I have two columns, Created On and Product, the data is how many support tickets were raised in 2019 for each product.

Created On is Date format and ranges from 01/01/2019 to 31/01/2019
Product contains 122 different product names
There are 36,165 rows.

I was hoping on to have the list of 122 products on the Y axis and date along the X axis, with a line for each of the 122 products, with origins to show tickets created for each product on each day in 2019.
I wanted to have the ability to use check boxes to filter on specific products and show hide certain products in the line chart. I have played around and researched this with no idea if this is even possible I am certainly not making any progress.

Any advice on if what I am trying to achieve is not possible or tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Pivot chart perhaps.

Comment: That is currently what I am testing right at this moment. I was able to create a pivot chart and now I am trying to figure out if I can do this with line charts and multiple lines.